# RESTful - reset password

Tags: api, rest, uri

My question is similar to the following to existing questions

- [RESTful API: How to model 'request new password'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683543/restful-api-how-to-model-request-new-password)
- [RESTful reset password and confirm email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664154/restful-reset-password-and-confirm-email)

Except where they differ from mine is that I won't have the user Id at the time of requesting the reset, just their email address. E.g. my existing API is:

```
GET /users
POST /users
GET /users/{userId}
PUT /users/{userId}
```

`userId` in these examples are auto generated Ids.

Now I want to model an API where a password reset email can be requested. At this point the `userId` will not be known. So I was thinking of a few options and wondered if there was an established best practice.

My gut feeling is that this is the most appropriate approach.

```
PUT /users/password-reset/{emailAddress}
```

However, I could also expect that a user search could be conducted first to get the correct Id, but it feels unnecessarily chatty to me.

Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about the best practices but I would certainly like to experiment with the "[Code-on-Demand](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_7)" part of RESTful style here; so that the email ID is not visible in the HTTP traffic.

Keep a set of simple public-private key encryption algorithms on server side. And randomly send one algorithm on request to "forgot-password" page. Use this algorithm and public key to encrypt the email-ID and

```
PUT /users/password-reset/{encryptedEmailAddress}
```